# Dynamically show text depending on form result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple form, which looks like this:

```
Team 1
<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
<input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' readonly />
<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />

Team 2
<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity2' />
<input type='text' name='quantity2' value='0' class='qty' readonly />
<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity2' />
```

[image]

When one of Teams has set number 3 I want to appear that team's name dynamically below. Something like "Team1/Team 2 is the winner!". And when I change the number next to the name of team, I want the text "Team1/Team2 is the winner!" to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.qty').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val() == 3){
    // do this
  }
  else {
    // do the other thing
  }
})
```

Comment: Note that `.val()` method returns a string. Either convert the string into a number or use the `==` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some sort of div with the message you want to show and hide like this:

`<div class="message" style="display:none;">Team 1 is the winner!</div>`

You can use jQuery to target those buttons and listen for a click event like this:

```
$('.qtyminus, .qtyplus').click(function(){...});
```

Then within the `click()` callback function, you can handle checking :

```
$('.qtyminus, .qtyplus').click(function(){
  var score = $(this).siblings(".qty");
  if($(this).hasClass("qtyplus")){
    $(score).val(parseInt($(score).val())+1);
  }
  else{
    $(score).val(parseInt($(score).val())-1);
  }

  if($(score).val()==3){
    $('.message').show();
  }
  else{
    $('.message').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle? I can't make it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found a mistake. Give the values Team1 3-0 Team2 and then change it to 3-1. The text disappear. How to fix that? the text should be shown always when one of the teams has a value of 3